# Do intrinsic fortran routines compute results in double precision if input is double precision

Tags: fortran

The question is trivial, but I couldn't find a definitive answer so far. When using one of fortran's intrinsic mathematical functions, such as `sqrt(x)` with double precision input, will the result also be computed in double precision? In other words: Are these intrinsic funtions interfaces which call different functions depending on the kind of the input? I know that specific subroutines like `dsqrt(x)` exist for double precision, but I also know that double precision was changed from a separate data type to a kind of the real type at some point, so is there any difference between `sqrt` and `dsqrt` in fortran 90 and newer?